# Display Number of Active Members

Tags: members, global-variables

I'd like to be able to display the number of "active" members on a site. Ideally this would be something like "number of members who have logged in in the past 30 days".

Barring that, I'd settle for the total number of combined members in a set of member groups, like: group_1 + group_3 + group_5 = total number of members.

What do you think is the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So both of the above should done done relatively easy with the query tool...

The SQL you'll need is :

```
SELECT count(*) as active_members from exp_members WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(last_visit) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

The second one would just be :

```
SELECT count(*) as active_members from exp_members where group_id=1 OR group_id=3 OR group_id=5;
```

You'll simply be able to get the value using {active_members} from within the Query module.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A small edit in the first query of above answer: SELECT count(*) as active_members from exp_members WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(last_visit) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY); as last_visit is being stored as unit timestamp.

Comment: use WHERE group_id = '1' OR group_id = '3' OR group_id = '5'
Using AND will return 0 for active_members. You can't be a member of all 3 groups at once.